# XODO Pdf Reader: how to open PDF document outside of the Android app (Ionic-based)

Tags: android, angular, pdf, ionic-framework, mobile

when I open PDF file using XODO Pdf Reader from my Android app (written in Ionic framework), it opens within the app.

If I use another PDF app, it opens outside of the app.

Is it possible to somehow configure XODO and/or change the app so that the PDF opens outside of the app with XODO?

What I have:

[image]

What I want: (but with XODO)

[image]

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is related to Activity launch mode: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#ManifestForTasks, in particular here Xodo is using "singleTop" so this is the expected behaviour. You can provide your feedback to the Xodo team at support@xodo.com.